# Llamar un PageMethod con ajax desde un WebForm dentro de un proyecto de mvc

Tags: jquery, asp.net, mvc, webforms

Quisiera saber por que me marca este error "404 (Not Found)" cuando intento llamar un WebMethod con ajax desde un WebForm o aspx, 
ahora el detalle es que el webform se encuentra dentro de un proyecto Mvc no se si tenga algo que ver

dejo el código de como lo estoy llamado desde el js.
de ante mano muchas gracias.

código js

```
$.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            data: "",
            url: "../AspNetForms/WebForm1.aspx/MR_Operaciones",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function(result){
                alert("todo bien ");
            },
            error: function (result) {

                alert("Algún problema debe haber…");
            }
        });
```

código en el C#:

```
[WebMethod]
    public static List<object> MR_Operaciones()
    {
        List<object> list = new List<object>();
        try
        {

                    return new List<object>() { "", "listaparametros", "listacontroles" };                    

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return new List<object>() { ex.Message };
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

En data coloca el nombre del método, y en URL solo deja la ruta de la página

```
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        data: "MR_Operaciones",
        url: "../AspNetForms/WebForm1.aspx",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(result){
            alert("todo bien ");
        },
        error: function (result) {

            alert("Algún problema debe haber…");
        }
    });
```